# Is there an adjective meaning "pertaining to friction"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

A friend and I were discussing Apple earbuds. I said that the cables used to be coated with smooth plastic, but on the newer ones, the coating is closer to rubber, so the cables get tangled up easily.

I wanted to say, "I don't like the new, frictive cables." The only problem being that "frictive" isn't a word.

I've searched the OED and thesaurus.com, but haven't come up with a good word meaning "pertaining to friction" or "having the property of offering friction when rubbed." Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I’d call them low-grip and high-grip, perhaps.

Comment: Why not *rubbery*?

Comment: @jxh Because "rubbery", to me, is more about an object's consistency or the way it bends and stretches, than how its surface grips: I'd say fried squid or raw chicken breasts are rubbery, though quite slick.

Comment: Less slippery .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the engineering company where I used to work, we'd probably have said *grippier*, or  that the old ones were  slippery.

*Frictional* means *pertaining to friction*, but in the sense of forces rather than material properties

You could also say you preferred the *low-friction* version to be *high-friction*.

Comment: I'm a landscape Architect, in regard to paving I am used to talking about surfaces being either 'grippier' or 'slip resistant', 'grippier' I'd use in conversation, but in correspondence or documentation I would talk about a 'higher level of slip resistance'..

Comment: @Spagirl in between there's also "high-friction (surface)", which is what I'd probably use if "grippy" was too informal (but simple clarity wins over formality in much of what I write, like instructions).

Comment: Thanks! In this context, I like "grippier". It's a fun and readily understood word, like "stabby".

Answer (score 1):

I searched OED for [all the mentions of *friction*](http://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&f_0=Definition&page=1&pageSize=100&q_0=friction&scope=SENSE&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch) and found

- frictive (obsolete; "obtained by friction")
- frictionable (rare; "liable to undergo friction")
- frictional ("of or pertaining to friction, moved or produced by friction")

*Frictionable* would appear to be the one you need, although *frictional* is likely to be better understood, even if it causes mechanical engineers to wince or roll their eyes.

> **frictionable,** *adj.*
>   *rare.*
>
> Liable to undergo friction.

Comment: What about “fricative”, used in linguistics?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs It's in the list, but means *sounded* by friction, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: I thought of "fricative", but that's a term of art in linguistics.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for looking this up. I thought I had checked the OED, but I guess I was wrong.
The difference between "frictionable" and "frictional" seems to be akin to the difference between "flammable" and "inflammable" ("capable of burning" vs. "capable of catching fire". I don't remember which is which). For that reason I have a slight preference for "frictional", but I can be swayed.

Comment: @Arens *Frictional* means "of friction," so you could have a frictional force (a force generated by friction); *frictionable* means "able to be frictioned on", for want of a better phrase.

Comment: I accept and agree with all you say here, but I think the term "the higher-friction variety" would be better understood.